# Eclipse plugins that supports TDD

Tags: java, eclipse, tdd

do you know about some interesting Eclipse plugins that supports Test driven development?

Comment: And how do you imagine it? The plugin won't let you write code until tests are written? Or write code for tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Infinitest and JUnitMax do "Continuos Testing". All your tests are run in the background and testing errors appear as error annotations as if they are compiler errors. Interesting indeed ;).

http://infinitest.github.com/

http://www.threeriversinstitute.org/junitmax/

Answer (score 3):

Pulse is a visually nice plugin that lets you track your TDD flow.

http://www.happyprog.com/pulse/