# What is Test Driven Development(TDD) in Java and how to automate test cases

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, unit-testing, tdd

The idea is to try and find the minimum number of clicks required on a remote with 0-9, forward, backward and previous channel buttons to go through a given sequence of channels in a given range. Channels that are blocked will be skipped automatically while pressing forward or backward buttons.

Here is my working code for it (I have been frowned upon many times for just asking questions without the homework so i decided to do a complete working code with this one.). How can I automate test cases for it using java and eclipse to exhibit TDD principles? Eclipse is the editor i am coding in.

```
    package Algo;

    import java.util.*;

    public class indix {

        public static void main(String args[]) {

            String range;
            String blocked;
            String sequence;
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            // Read the Input
            range = in.nextLine();
            blocked = in.nextLine();
            sequence = in.nextLine();

            String blk[] = blocked.split(" ");
            String seq[] = sequence.split(" ");
    //Put the blocked channels into a hash-map
            HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

            for (int j = 1; j < blk.length ; j++) {
                hm.put(Integer.parseInt(blk[j]), 1);
            }

            String temp[] = range.split(" ");
          //  Start Range and End Range for the channels available from input string 
            int s_range = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
            int e_range = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
            temp = null;

            for (String s : blk) {
                System.out.print(s + " ");

            }
            System.out.println();
            for (String s : seq) {
                System.out.print(s + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

                //Initialize a cost array for storing costs as we browse through the sequence
                int[] cost = new int[e_range + 1];

            cost[0] = 0;
    //Curr is the Current channel we are on, next is the channel we want to hop to and diff is the difference in number of channles in between curr and next
            int diff;
            int sum_cost = 0;
            Integer next;
               //Assuming that initially we start with the first channel in the range
                Integer curr = s_range;
            System.out.println("Start, End " + s_range + "," + e_range + " Seq.length "+seq.length);
            for (int i = 1; i < seq.length; i++) {

                    //Assign one by one the channels from the seqeunce in which we want to browse from the sequence list
                        next = Integer.parseInt(seq[i]);
                diff = next - curr;
                System.out.println("Diff = " + diff);
                int start, diff_adj = 0;
                start = curr + 1;


                   //Find out the number of blocked channels which will be auto skipped in between
                while (true) {

                                    if (start == next)
                        break;
                    if (hm.containsKey(start))
                        diff_adj++;
                    start++;

                }

                System.out.println("Diff Adj= " + diff_adj);
    //Adjust the difference with number of blocked channels skipped
                diff = diff - diff_adj;

                System.out.println("Length of current channel is "
                        + seq[i].length());
    //if the differene is greate than the length of the channel, the use the length of channel as the cost, else the diff value(i.e if from 102 to 104 it is easy to press forward button twice rather then pressing 104 which is three buttons. From 102 to 108, it is cheaper to press 108 directly as it costs three lcicks rather than one by one incrementing from 102. Account from skiped channels as you do this.)
                if (diff > seq[i].length())
                    cost[next] = seq[i].length() + cost[curr];
                else
                    cost[next] = diff + cost[curr];
                curr = next;
                System.out.println("The current cost is this channel is" + next
                        + "," + diff);

                sum_cost = cost[next];
            }

            System.out.println("Minimum cost is" + sum_cost);

        }

    }

My output is:

    2 103 108 
    3 102 106 109 
    Start, End 100,200 Seq.length 4
    Diff = 2
    Diff Adj= 0
    Length of current channel is 3
    The current cost is this channel is102,2
    Diff = 4
    Diff Adj= 1
    Length of current channel is 3
    The current cost is this channel is106,3
    Diff = 3
    Diff Adj= 1
    Length of current channel is 3
    The current cost is this channel is109,2
    Minimum cost is7
```

Comment: Do you understand, what test-driven development is? A great part of it is first writing tests and then the code that should be tested. It looks like you developed the code first and want to write tests now which, by definition, is not test-driven development. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: I have never worked with TDD, this is a part of an Interview question I was asked to solve, so i solved it, but how do I apply TDD to this.
Is there a framework wherein i write test cases and then run my code against it. The entire idea to let your code fail and then build a solution around it is confusing, so i wrote the code and need help in understanding what possibly could have been my approach if I wanted to Solve this using TDD. I did not want to ask a question without even having attempted it.

Comment: If you're asking for testing frameworks, JUnit and TestNG are the two names you'll most commonly hear. So, the approach would be: Write tests with one of the above frameworks that will test your logic. These tests would have the sequence and the manually calculated ideal result. Then you'd write your functions which calculate the result and the tests would check whether the actual result is equal to the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

We can follow TDD after adding available plugin in eclipse. Eclipse plugins that supports TDD([Plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936945/eclipse-plugins-that-supports-tdd))
Getting started with TDD explained on 
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073090/testing-debugging/getting-started-with-test-driven-development.html

Answer (score 1):

when you talk about TDD then you think of all scenarios/test-cases before actually implementing it, then w.r.t all scenarios you write your test cases and let them fail.
one by one you make them pass by giving appropriate implementation. ([Red green re-factor](http://agileinaflash.blogspot.in/2009/02/red-green-refactor.html))

to perform TDD you need tools and framework, find a more info [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072724/testing-debugging/best-practices-for-test-driven-development.html)